# Integrated graphics card performs the same as / faster than dedicated on OpenGL Application

Tags: opengl, rendering, lwjgl

I'm working on a project using LWJGL with OpenGL and after a recent Windows update,

the performance has dropped drastically

my system is lenovo Z50 laptop with 840m(2gb VRAM) as dedicated and 4400 HD graphics as integrated and somehow they seem to be performing the same.

here is a sample console output:

**INTEGRATED:**

```
VGL 0.1 | OpenGL 4.3.0 - Build 20.19.15.4642

GL_VENDOR   : Intel

GL_RENDERER : Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400

Rendering >> 10000 sprites !

FPS : 357, UPS : 59

FPS : 396, UPS : 60

FPS : 401, UPS : 60

**DEDICATED:**

VGL 0.1 | OpenGL 4.6.0 NVIDIA 391.01

GL_VENDOR   : NVIDIA Corporation

GL_RENDERER : GeForce 840M/PCIe/SSE2

Rendering >> 10000 sprites !

FPS : 351, UPS : 59

FPS : 416, UPS : 60

FPS : 417, UPS : 60
```

It is strange since I'm getting 50% more performance with the 840m in every game/graphics intensive application

I have tried reinstalling my GPU drivers, reverting back to the previous version of windows,

adjusting settings in the NVIDIA control panel, but I haven't been able to get it working again.

PS: I'm running the newest driver for my GPU

Comment: What does _UPS_ stand for? The limit of 60 looks very suspicious.

Comment: Updates Per Second

Comment: Well, whatever that is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 2):

> Im working on a project using LWJGL with OpenGL and after a recent Windows update, the performance has dropped drastically

I'd not be surprised if this is due to the mitigations that have been introduced in response to discovery/publishing of the Meltdown/Spectre attack vectors. The way hybrid graphics works is, that the dedicated GPU will do some rendering and then copy the result into the memory of the integrated graphics adapter that the display is connected to.

This copy operation is controlled by the drivers and it takes a few jumps between kernel/user space to coordinate (also may involve context switches). However the Meltdown attack vector added some overhead in address space management at every kernel/user space switch which unfortunately hits hard anything that has to work with address spaces… which would also include anything that manages copy operations between devices on memory which is also accessible to user space (like for example the render target buffers of a graphics application and the source image buffers of a compositor).

We'll probably see driver optimizations to deal with this new reality, getting back some of the performance.

That besing said: For any framerate that goes beyond the rate at which things are pushed to the display you're wasting transfer bandwidth anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Hopefully the issue is resolved.

Comment: As for not limiting the fps, i use it to measure performance.The actual finished product will have it's swap interval set to the display's refresh rate

Comment: @Vlad: For measuring performance it's usually better to measure the time required for actual rendering, instead of relying on the "noisy" side channel of counting the frame rate. Use queries for that: [glGenQueries](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenQueries.xhtml), [glBeginQuery/glEndQuery](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBeginQuery.xhtml), [glQueryCounter](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glQueryCounter.xhtml), [glGetQueryObject](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetQueryObject.xhtml)

Comment: @Vlad: Have a look in my `pointoverdrawbench` on how to use them: https://github.com/datenwolf/pointoverdrawbench/blob/master/main.c – also has some nice stats functions (running average and standard deviation) you can use, too.